# Archive data and run reports on it

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, report

I have a mysql database which its size is growing so fast due the amount of inserts at minute,

Since larger DB slow down performance, and the old date is only used for reports, I was thinking to move that data out of the DB.

So I have some questions about it

1. Is it a good idea?
2. How can I do the archiving?
3. How can I run reports on the archived data?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The level of performance decrease due to database size is very relative.  When your tables are properly indexed and your report queries are efficient, the database size can have almost negligible effect on its performance.

My suggestion is rather than moving data from your production database to an archive database, instead build your reporting to only ask for 'recent' records.  For instance, instead of bumping off all records older than a year, modify your report queries with:

`where date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR);`

That way you still have access to all your data if you need it, and your reporting suffers very minimally for the database size.  Also making sure your date is indexed will help.